# laravel not seeing my localhost database error : SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, model-view-controller

I have a problem in which my Laravel is not detecting my localhost phpmyadmin database my config is set to local host and I've tried changing the ip to 127.0.0.1, I'm kind off stuck with this at the moment.

database config:

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('127.0.0.1'),
        'database'  => env('credito'),
        'username'  => env('root'),
        'password'  => env(''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

   
],
```

Comment: Why did u edit database.php
You where supposed to change the `.env`

Comment: Any upDate on this problem ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

**.env** Update the values in .env thats the correct way.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Another problem Maybe**  that Laravel is not detecting your application environment.
you can check what environment it is using with

`command line: php artisan env`

Answer (score 0):

```
Just make sure that you have the same credentials 
        'host' => env('127.0.0.1'),
        'database'  => env('credito'),
        'username'  => env('root'),
        'password'  => env(''),on your config/database.php and .env file, restart your apache server
```